# Android ListView: how to add various itens in a row in a dynamic way?

Tags: android, listview, dynamic, row

I want some tips in how to complete one task.

We got three EditTexts, a button and a llistview.

The idea here is when the button is pressed, the texts from the three EditTexts will be show in a listview, side by side, giving the impression that we got a table here.

The problem here is I don't know how to do it. I've tried to search something on the net, but I just got nothing.

I'd really appreciate if you could help.
Thaks for the attention and have a nice day.

Comment: Ok, please post the code that you have. For instance the database adapter and how you insert rows.

Comment: Actually, Sam, I don't have nothing done yet and i'm not using a database. Now that I get your attention, please answer this question: for solve my task i need a CustomAdapter, since I want to put three textviews in a row of the ListView. Also i'd like to add/remove in a dynamic way, rows in the ListView, after a button is pressed. In this case, do I need to put all the data i get from the EditText to a kind of Array to so put in the ListView? Sorry for not  specifying this doubt on the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple ways to achieve what you want. If I'm understanding correctly you have a listview and a button. When you click the button, you want 3 editTexts to appear in your listview side by side so that it looks like a table.

The simplest solution is have your list item layout, inflated in your listadapter, simply be a linearlayout with weightSum="3" containing 3 edittexts with layout_weight="1" and layout_width="0dp"

so your list_item.xml would look something like:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:weightSum="3">
    <EditText android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" 
        android:visibility="invisible"/>
    <EditText android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" 
        android:visibility="invisible"/>
    <EditText android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" 
        android:visibility="invisible"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Then, in the onClick for your button, iterate through the children of the list row and set the visibilities to visible.

As for adding rows dynamically, use a listadapter and a collection and use the notifydatasetchanged to update the list when your collection gains/loses items.

Comment: Thanks for the tips, bro. But I want to know too if instead of the edittext, we got some textviews to be show after the button be pressed.  for solve this task guess I need a CustomAdapter, since I want to put three textviews in a row of the ListView. Also i'd like to add/remove in a dynamic way, rows in the ListView, after a button is pressed. In this case, do I need to put all the data i get from some EditText, to a kind of Array to so put in the ListView?

Comment: Yep, instead of the edittext, just use textview if that's what you need. You will need to implement an Adapter of some kind. What you will want to do is store your data into some kind of collection (array, arraylist, whatever). Use this collection as the dataset for the adapter.